# Hibernate create record in russian language appears as question marks mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, rest

I am trying to save a record in my DB in russian language but it appears as question marks
I use Hibernate Jpa with Spring data
My DB charset is UTF8
My table utf8mb4
in hibernate properties I set

```
hibernate.connection.useUnicode = true
    hibernate.connection.characterEncoding = utf-8 
    hibernate.connection.CharSet = utf-8
```

Still the Russian language appears as Question marks. What else can I do, 
thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check that Database tables has it also set. 
Also a nice approach to distinguish if it's hibernate or DB problem would be to insert record via MySQL Workbench and check if it's saved correctly. If not - than definitely check table encoding, if yes, check that correct character encoding is really passed to hibernate (maybe you'll need `jpa.properties.hibernate.` key)

Comment: yes, its saved correctly when I insert via MySQL Workbench

Comment: try adding `?UseUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8` to your connection URL

Comment: I added ?UseUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8 and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://2cyr.com/decode/ Universal Cyrillic decoder
try this tool may be the character is from different encoding (not cp1252).
check this encoding ISO-8859-5 ISO8859_5 Eastern European (Cyrillic-based: Bulgarian, Byelorussian, Macedonian, Russian, Serbian, Ukrainian).
if the character is ok then change table
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-cyrillic-sets.html